# How can I scan for rows based on a row pattern in HBase shell?

Tags: nosql, hbase, hbasestorage

I want to scan rows in a HTable from the HBase shell using row matching some pattern.

For example, I have the following table data:

```
    row:r1_t1  column:cf:a, timestamp=1461911995948,value=v1
    row:r2_t2  column:cf:a, timestamp=1461911995949,value=v2
    row:s1_t1  column:cf:a, timestamp=1461911995950,value=q1
    row:s2_t2  column:cf:a, timestamp=1461911995951,value=q2
```

Based on the above data I want to find the rows that contain 't1' :

```
    row:r1_t1  column:cf:a, timestamp=1461911995948,value=v1
    row:s1_t1  column:cf:a, timestamp=1461911995950,value=q1
```

I know I can scan the table with PrefixFilter, but this method takes the rows that starts with the specified filter.

```
    scan 'test', {FILTER => "(PrefixFilter('s')"}
```

Is there a similar way of scanning the table based on filtering the rows with the pattern matching in the middle of the row name?

Comment: Did you find any alternative techniques other than what I suggested below ?

Comment: No, the method with RowFilter works fine, so I've stopped looking for an alternative.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
hbase(main):003:0> scan 'test', {ENDROW => 't1'}
```

In general, Using a `PrefixFilter` can be slow because it performs a table scan until it reaches the prefix.

Also can use RowFilter with SubstringComparator
like below

Can use `RowFilter` with `SubstringComparator` like below

```
hbase(main):003:0> import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.filter.CompareFilter
hbase(main):005:0> import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.filter.SubstringComparator
hbase(main):006:0> scan 'test', {FILTER => org.apache.hadoop.hbase.filter.RowFilter.new(CompareFilter::CompareOp.valueOf('EQUAL'),SubstringComparator.new("searchkeyword"))}
```

Comment: When I am using this method on a large table I get `ERROR: Call id=14, waitTime=60001, operationTimeout=60000 expired.`  Is there a way of increasing waitTime?

Comment: In hbase-site.xml you can try increasing hbase.rpc.timeout to 1800000

Comment: I would refer you to read this https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/hbase-the-definitive/9781491905845/ch04.html . In general you have huge data in your table and you want search rows with some pattern, I would suggest FuzzyRowFilter using java api(see the example in the link)  It has 2 parts fixed or known part of the rowkey and variable or unknown part of the key This will handle huge data efficiently.